# java ee 6 aop aspectj

Tags: eclipse-rcp, aop, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, aspectj

Is it possible to integrate `aspectj` with `java ee 6`? 
I want to do this because I have some entities (that I transfer on a standalone eclipse client) and I would like to write once and use everywhere... using interceptors from EE it is not working in client. (I just want to notify listeners each time I access a `set` method)

I am using

- `glassfish 3` as `AS`
- `java ee 6`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible.

The simplest option is to use compile-time weaving. The Eclipse [AJDT plugin](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/) can compile for you during development. Ant and Maven 2 also supports compiling with AspectJ. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548478/148608) I have written a response on how to compile with Ant.

It's also possible to load-time weave the aspects into your code. That is a little bit more difficult, since it's different ways to do it on different application containers. Standalone you have to use a JVM argument to enable weaving.
An example:

```
-javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar
```

I have written more about load-time weaving [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429298/148608).

With compile-time weaving I have good experience on standalone clients, IBM Websphere, Jetty, Tomcat and JBoss. The same code works on all platforms and produces the same result. I have no bad experiences with other platforms regarding AspectJ, I just haven't tried them.